# How to add rate of change calculation to data.frame and group IDs together

Tags: r

I calculated yearly averages for thousands of IDs using plyr, but now I am having trouble figuring out how to efficiently calculate the rate of change.
For example:

```
ID  Year  Mean
1A  1994  1
1A  1995  2
1A  1997  4
1B  2000  3
1B  2012  4
1B  2013  5
```

Can I use a loop with lm() to efficiently calculate the rate of change for each ID?

I also tried using diff() but I couldn't figure out how to calculate the rate of change for each ID in one go.

I'm also trying to figure out how to add this as a new column to the data.frame. I have this as a wide format table too with each year occupying it's own column and the corresponding means listed by Year and ID, but can you calculate rate of change from the widecast table?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diff function returns a vector that is 1 element shorter than it's input (can't compute a difference for the first observation). The calculation fails because the vector lengths don't match. As for the grouping issue, use `ifelse` and a lag function to conditionally null out the first case for each ID. See functions below:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("1A", "1A", "1A", "1B", "1B", "1B"),
                 Year = c(1994, 1995, 1997, 2000, 2012, 2013),
                 Mean = c(1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

delta <- function(x) diff(c(NA, x))      # inserts an NA value at the beginning
prior <- function(x) c(NA, head(x, -1))  # lagging function using base R    
rate  <- function(x) delta(x) / prior(x) # for readability

df$growth_rate <- ifelse(df$ID == prior(df$ID), rate(df$Mean), NA)

df
```

Result

```
  ID Year Mean growth_rate
1 1A 1994    1          NA
2 1A 1995    2   1.0000000
3 1A 1997    4   1.0000000
4 1B 2000    3          NA
5 1B 2012    4   0.3333333
6 1B 2013    5   0.2500000
```

Comment: Edited to account for the ID-groups

Comment: @lmo -- good catch. the `dplyr` package was loaded in my RStudio environment (unintentional). I updated the post to correct. My personal preference is to stick with base R if I can, and load packages when using multiple functions from the package, or when the function does something that is more non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

A common method in these situations is to use `ave` for grouping in base R.

```
df$growth <- with(df, ave(Mean, ID,
                          FUN=function(x) c(NA, diff(x) / tail(x, -1))))
```

which returns

```
df
  ID Year Mean growth
1 1A 1994    1     NA
2 1A 1995    2   0.50
3 1A 1997    4   0.50
4 1B 2000    3     NA
5 1B 2012    4   0.25
6 1B 2013    5   0.20
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this is helpful for anyone, this is my final solution using a wide format data.frame for my data:

```
result.tab <-data.frame(ID=df$ID, coff=NaN, rsq=NaN, Pvalue=NaN)

for(i in 1:198){
  temp <- df[i,]
  temp_long <- gather(temp, "Year", "Salinity", 2:54)

  temp_long$Year <- as.numeric(temp_long$Year)

  temp.lm <- lm(log(Salinity)~Year, data=temp_long, na.action = na.omit)

  result.tab[i,2] <- temp.lm$coefficients[2]
  result.tab[i,3] <- summary(temp.lm)$r.squared
  result.tab[i,4] <- anova(temp.lm)$'Pr(>F)'[1]

}
```